# fadeIn() an invisible list item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list whose `li`s are invisible (`display:none`) to begin with.

I want to make a specific `li` visible with a JS function. How can I do that?

I've tried `$("#my-list li:nth-child(1)").fadeIn()` but that only works if the `ul` is visible to begin with.

Here's my code:

```css
ul.hide > li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hide" id="my-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to answer [this question](https://bountify.co/i). Feel free to take a stab at it!

Comment: Make the `ul` visible.  An invisible element cannot have visible children.

Comment: The code you've tried is working fine.. But I didn't hide the main `ul` See here: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/PSQMd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like bdares said, an invisible element cannot have a visible child. So what you said about the code is true: ul has to be visible to begin with.

Looking at the html code you could probably just remove `class="hide"` which will make the ul visible.

However if you can't do that, an alternative is to use Javascript to make ul visible on the fly. Instead of just:

```
$("#my-list li:nth-child(1)").fadeIn();
```

Do

```
$("#my-list").show();
$("#my-list li:nth-child(1)").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

<strike>`$("#my-list").show(0).children("li:nth-child(1)").fadeIn();`</strike>

`$("#my-list").show().children("li:nth-child(1)").fadeIn();`

<strike>Let me explain you why `.show(0)` is better than `.show()`. When you use `.show()`, it gives a transition, which eases out the DOM Element, which is not needed. It is like showing a hidden element and hiding it smoothly, which is not accepted.</strike>

Comment: @PraveenKumar Check the document of http://api.jquery.com/show/, not as you said.

Comment: @xdazz Yeah, I might be wrong, may be old jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/q9Hz2/1/ both are same. I tested now.